# Запятая между прилагательными «широкий» и «спокойный»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-неоднородные-определения

Прошу прощения, что в последнее время задаю много вопросов. Это связано с началом учебного года. Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении между прилагательными "широкий" и "спокойный"? Если запятая нужна, то чем это обусловлено?

**В субботу ранним утром, еле-еле ощутимым за серой пеленою широкого(,) спокойного дождя, я пошел в лес за грибами.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы тоже поставила запятую — но совершенно на других основаниях.

> **1.** Между однородными определениями, не связанными союзами, ставится запятая.
> Согласованные определения являются однородными: <...>
> **5)** если представляют собой художественные определения: *Одни кузнечики дружно трещат, и утомителен... этот **непрестанный, кислый** и **сухой** звук* (Т.); *Его **бледно-голубые, стеклянные** глаза разбегались* (Т.); *Старуха закрыла **свинцовые, погасшие** глаза* (М. Г.); то же при употреблении определения-прилагательного в переносном значении: *круглые, рыбьи глаза мальчика; тонкие, журавлиные ноги*...

Прилагательные [*широкий*](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) и [*спокойный*](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) в данном предложении являются [метафорами](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_literature/3053/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0) — словами, употребленными в переносном значении. По правилу между ними **всегда** ставится запятая.

**Для сравнения**

В прямом значении (без запятой):
*«Мессершмитт» сделал в небе **широкий спокойный** разворот и пошел к Бобруйску вслед за бомбардировщиками* (Константин Симонов. Живые и мертвые).

В переносном значении (с запятой):
***Широкий, спокойный** поток церковного хорала сменился целым морем органных звуков, которые только одному Паганини удавалось воспроизвести на скрипке* (А. К. Виноградов. Осуждение Паганини).

[Однородные и неоднородные определения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98#pp98)

Comment: Я тоже считаю прилагательные метафорами (мой голос за вас), но не могу понять образ, то есть представить себе этот дождь. Какой он, что объединяет эти метафоры, какое впечатление передает автор? Особенно сложно понимается   "широкий дождь". Даже посмотрела в  Интернете, но нашала только  широкий атмосферный ливень (ШАЛ) — «ливень» вторичных субатомных частиц https://kartaslov.ru/карта-знаний/Широкий+атмосферный+ливень   А здесь что?

Comment: Я думаю, что имеется в виду *широкая полоса дождя*, *широкий фронт осадков* (дождя). (https://ru.wikiquote.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8C) Похоже, нет?

Comment: Вот здесь есть классификация дождей)) https://dzen.ru/a/Y3d3xlIfuixOWAnB  Может, обложной дождь? Выходишь на улицу: погода безветренная, все небо серое, дождь на целый день. А в ху.д. литературе встречается такое определение?

Comment: Нашлось вот что, очень похожее: *Сквозь мрак спускающихся сумерек широкая полоса дождя надвигалась на них* (Нора Хесс). *Раскаты грома становились всё ворчливее, и стала видна широкая полоса дождя, идущая прямо на Ильичёво* (Катерина Сапьян).

Comment: Да, спасибо вам. Полосовой дождь? Но его, наверное, спокойным не назовешь. А как же наш персонаж вышел за грибами в такую ненадежную погоду? )  Мне хочется разгадать этот образ, насколько он правдив с художественной точки зрения. Вы бы стали использовать такое определение?  И автора этого текста я не могу найти.

Comment: С авторством текста, действительно, что-то странное. Вот здесь (https://www.cspu.ru/sveden/files/PD.01_Russkiy_yazyk_9kl.pdf; Текст 3. За грибами; стр. 34) имеется куча печатей и куча подписей, а автора нет. И в других "местах" нет.

Comment: Спасибо за поиски!  Ситуация немного проясняется. ДУмаю, такие диктанты сочиняются специально. Посмотрите, сколько там разных орфограмм, сколько предложений по пунктуации. В то же время текст связанный, кажется художественным на первый взгляд. Сочинить их не так уж сложно.  И все-таки, почему же широкий? Зачем им такая сложная метафора))

Answer (score 3):

**Ставится**!

> если в условиях контекста, характеризуя предмет с разных сторон,
> объединяются каким-либо общим признаком (внешним видом, сходством
> производимого ими впечатления, отнесением к отдаленному общему
> понятию, причинно-следственной связью и т. д.)

В субботу ранним утром, еле-еле ощутимым за серой пеленою ***широкого,спокойного*** дождя, я пошел в лес за грибами.

---

Думаю, что автору важно было показать **умеренность** дождя: он раскидистый и в то же время ненавязчивый. Здесь автору как раз пришли на помощь художественные определения, которые создали цельный образ непогоды. В другом контексте они вполне могли и не быть **однородными**.